# Regex for multiline patterns then they are following each other

Tags: regex, grep, pcregrep

I'm trying to find lines that have "aaa" and "bbb" in that order, and those strings are on different lines.

```
11 aaa blah blah
bbb blah blah
blah blah blah blah
aaa blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah
11 bbb blah blah
blah blah blah blah
```

With this multiline pattern `.*?(.|\n)*?` I get all the lines between my strings:

```
11 aaa blah blah
bbb blah blah

aaa blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah
11 bbb blah blah
```

But I need to match them only then they are following each other. E.g. aaa on the 1st line, bbb on the 2nd. The output should be:

```
11 aaa blah blah
bbb blah blah
```

Comment: Is this what you want: [regex101?](https://regex101.com/r/TuZCy3/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for the help, but the regex you provided does not match the subject string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```sh
pcregrep -Mo '.*aaa.*\R.*bb.*' file
```

The `M` option allows `pcregrep` to "see" line breaks and match them with the regex and `o` will output the texts matched.

The pattern matches

- `.*aaa.*` - a line containing `aaa`
- `\R` - a line break
- `.*bbb.*` - a line containing `bbb`